# Laravel chunkbyid for joins

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When i use chunkById on a Query Builder with joins I am not getting the output

```
 DB::table('cs')
 ->join('hw','hw.p1', '=', 'cs.awb')
 ->where('cs.dv','hw')
 ->chunkById(100, function ($hw_orders) use (&$hwCount) {
 foreach ($hw_orders as $hwd){
  Log::info('Number ' . $hwd->awb);
 });
```

I want to know how I could chunk this data with joins.
Thank you

Comment: No i am not getting any error but there are records ... its not going into chunkbyid function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing additional  `param` to `chunkById` as column name

```
DB::table('cs')
        ->join('hw','hw.p1', '=', 'cs.awb')
        ->where('cs.dv','hw')
        ->chunkById(100, function ($hw_orders) {
            foreach ($hw_orders as $hwd) {
                Log::info('Number ' . $hwd->awb);
            }
        },'cs.awb','p1');
```

For Reference

```
/**
     * Chunk the results of a query by comparing IDs.
     *
     * @param  int  $count
     * @param  callable  $callback
     * @param  string|null  $column
     * @param  string|null  $alias
     * @return bool
     */
    public function chunkById(
                 $count, 
                 callable $callback, 
                 $column = null, 
                 $alias = null
                 )
```